Nuxt3 & Apache2 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
I created a middleware for authorization. When I run 'pnpm nuxt dev,' it works without any issues. However, after building and then running 'pnpm nuxt start,' I get the 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' error after logging in
middleware file;
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, form) => {
    if(process.server){
        const here = to.name as string
        const auths = ['login', 'signup', 'password-reset']        
        const isAuth = Boolean(useCookie('tok').value)

        if(isAuth && auths.includes(here)){
            return navigateTo('/', {external: true, replace: true})
        }else if(!isAuth && !auths.includes(here)){  
            return navigateTo('/login', {external: true, replace: true})
        }
    }   
})

Apache2 Config file;
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    ServerName localhost
    RequestHeader set Host %{HTTP_HOST}s
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    RequestHeader set X-Real-IP %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
    RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-For %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    
</VirtualHost>

.env file for nuxt3;
NITRO_HOST=localhost
NITRO_PORT=3000

Im using nuxt  version 3.6.5

Isn't it an infinite redirection? Have you thought of all the possible values that your middleman could receive?

@kissu Yes, it is an endless redirect, but when I say 'npm nuxt dev' it does not happen, it takes time when I go live.

That's probably because the redirection is not triggered initially for some reason. But it's good that it crashes when you're building it, that way you do not ship any bugs that were not spotted during dev!

@kissu I still haven't solved the problem but I will write a component called Login for this, it works like this. I think the problem is caused by the constant redirection being triggered, but I don't understand how this happens. I will provide v-if related controls in app.vue with the login component, etc., I will run it like this.
